# How to convert from GDKColor to GDKRGBA struct?

Tags: gtk3

I'm converting some code from GdkColor to GdkRGBA. This the the GTK+2 code:

```
f_colors = img->current_slide->font_brdr_color;
color.red   = (gint)( f_colors[0] * 0xffff );
color.green = (gint)( f_colors[1] * 0xffff );
color.blue  = (gint)( f_colors[2] * 0xffff );
gtk_color_button_set_color( GTK_COLOR_BUTTON( img->sub_brdr_color ), &color ); 
gtk_color_button_set_alpha( GTK_COLOR_BUTTON( img->sub_brdr_color ),
                                (gint)(f_colors[3] * 0xffff ) );
```

color is a GdkRGBA struct while f_colors is an array of double. The code perfectly work as the color button is set to the color I use but if I turn the code into GTK+3 the color of gtk_color_chooser doesn't reflect the color I use.

How can I convert the array of doubles into a GdkRGBA struct?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it!

```
f_colors = img->current_slide->font_brdr_color;
color.red   = f_colors[0];
color.green = f_colors[1];
color.blue  = f_colors[2];
```